# Can't import riot while using jspm

Tags: javascript, jspm, riot.js

I'm trying to use Riot 3.0.0 with jspm. I installed riot via `jspm install riot`. I can't manage to import and use riot. Here is my minimal test:

/app.js

```
import riot from 'riot';
riot.tag('test',
  `<h3>Lalalalala test 1-2-3</h3>`,
  function(opts) {}
);
var mountedTags = riot.mount('*');
```

In browser I get:

> (SystemJS) riot is undefined

In jspm_error log:

> MultipleErrors:
>   /Users/user/.jspm/packages/npm/riot@3.0.0/lib/browser/common/util/check.js:1:1:
>   Unexpected reserved word import
>   /Users/user/.jspm/packages/npm/riot@3.0.0/lib/browser/common/util/check.js:1:8:
>   Semi-colon expected

In browser I can confirm http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/js/jspm_packages/npm/riot@3.0.0/riot.js is loaded.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

---

When riot.min.js (3.0.0) is included in a separate  tag from CDN instead of importing, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having a similar problem, I just find out about [issue #2028](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/2084) on riot's github, you might want to follow that too.

Comment: @TsutomuKawamura thanks for the heads up, I'm aware. You guys are very responsive, that's amazing. Keep up the good work.